# how to integrate vue.js with django?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

This is the single page application with vue.js and it does some simple calculation and i am trying to implement this calculation in django but it is not giving me the result I want.
Here I made the array in the vue.js dynamic and this is displaying me only the image of the product perfectly but not `product.name` and `product.sell_price` and also  `@click.prevent="addToCart(product)"`this function is not working ?? How can i solve it ?

**vue.js**

```
   <script src="{% static 'js/vue.js' %}"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/vue-resource.js' %}"></script>
    <script>

 new Vue({
    el: '#posApp',
    
    data: {
        total: 0,
        discount: 0,
        products: [
            {% for product in products %}
                {
                    "id": {{product.id}},
                    "name": "{{product.name}}",
                    "image": "/media/{{product.image}}",
                    "price": {{product.sell_price}}
                },
              {% endfor %}

        ],
        cart: [],
        search: ""
    },
    methods: {

        addToCart: function(product){

            var found = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.cart.length; i++){
                if (this.cart[i].id === product.id){
                    this.cart[i].quantity++;
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                this.cart.push({
                    id: product.id,
                    name: product.name,
                    sell_price: product.sell_price,
                    quantity: 1
                });
            }

            this.total += product.sell_price;
        },
        inc: function(item){
            item.quantity++;
            this.total += item.sell_price;
        },
        dec: function(item){
            item.quantity--;
            this.total -= item.sell_price;
            if (item.quantity <= 0){
                var i = this.cart.indexOf(item);
                this.cart.splice(i, 1);
            }
        },
        removeFromCart: function(item){
            this.cart.splice(this.cart.indexOf(item), 1);
            this.total = this.total - (item.sell_price * item.quantity);
        },
        clearCart: function(){
            this.cart = [];
            this.total = 0;
            this.discount = 0;
        },
        payment: function(){
            this.cart = [];
            this.total = 0;
            this.discount = 0;
            alert('Transaction Completed');
        }
    },
    computed: {
        filteredProducts(){
            // var lowerTitle = product.title.toLowerCase();
            return this.products.filter((product) => {
                return product.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search);
            });
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

**html**

```
 <div class="col-md-3" v-for="product in filteredProducts" :key="product.id"> <!-- Inner-Col .// -->
                  <a href="#" @click.prevent="addToCart(product)">
                    <div class="box box-default pos-product-card"> <!-- /.box -->
                      <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" :src="product.image" alt="Card image cap">
                      <div class="box-body"> <!-- /.box-body -->
                        <h4 class="box-title">{{ product.name }}</h4>
                        <!-- <p class="box-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p> -->
                        <button class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
                      </div> <!-- /.box-body -->
                    </div> <!-- /.box -->
                  </a>
                </div>
{% for category in categories %}
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="category-{{category.id}}">

                <div class="row"> <!-- Inner-Row .// -->
                    {% for product in category.product_set.all %}
                   <div class="col-md-3" v-for="product in filteredProducts" :key="product.id"> <!-- Inner-Col .// -->
                  <a href="#" @click.prevent="addToCart(product)">
                    <div class="box box-default pos-product-card"> <!-- /.box -->
                      <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" :src="product.image" alt="Card image cap">
                      <div class="box-body"> <!-- /.box-body -->
                        <h4 class="box-title">{{ product.name }}</h4>
                        <!-- <p class="box-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p> -->
                        <button class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
                      </div> <!-- /.box-body -->
                    </div> <!-- /.box -->
                  </a>
                </div>
                    {% endfor %}
     <table class="table table-hover text-center">
                                  <!-- <thead class="thead-dark"> -->
                                    <tr>
                                      <th>Item</th>
                                      <th>Quantity</th>
                                      <th>Rate</th>
                                      <th>Subtotal</th>
                                      <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                    </tr>
                                  <!-- </thead> -->
                                      <tr v-for="item in cart" :key="{{item.id}}">

                    <td><a href="#">{{ item.name }}</a></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-flat btn-xs btn-info p-1 mx-1" @click="inc(item.id)">+</button>[[ item.quantity ]]<button class="btn btn-flat p-1 mx-1 btn-xs btn-info" @click="dec(item.id)">-</button></td>
                    <td><span class="text-muted">{{ item.sell_price }}</span> </td>
                    <td>Rs {{ item.sell_price * item.quantity }}</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-outline-primary" @click="removeFromCart(item)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
                  </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="no-item-msg" v-if="cart.length === 0">No items in the cart.</div>
                              </div>
         <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                      <td>Total Items</td>
                      <td>{{ cart.length }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Total Amount</td>
                      <td>{{ total }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><span class="height-control">Discount (In Amount)</span></td>
                      <td><input type="number" v-model="discount" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="bg-dark">
                      <td>TO PAY</td>
                      <td>{{ total-discount }}</td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamic django variables`? How are they "dynamic"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few points for you to consider:

1. Seems like you have syntax collision in your html, because Django and Vue.js use same `{{` and `}}` to put variable. But, as Django will process your html **before** Vue, it will replace

   ````
   ``` <h4 class="box-title">{{ product.name }}</h4>```
   ````

by what it will find in context (Django tepmlate context on server side). You may check source or your page in browser, and probably you will see at that line:

`<h4 class="box-title"></h4>`

Because it will not find python `product` variable (and you actually meant js(vue) variable).

**Solution**:  use another Vue delimiters. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters. For example use `[[` instead of `{{` in Vue: an option to your Vue instance `delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],` and change that line (and other where you mean Vue variables) to

`<h4 class="box-title">[[ product.name ]]</h4>`

2. In Vue data you have *not* product.sell_price variable, as when you doing

```
  {% for product in products %}
     {
      "id": {{product.id}},
      "name": "{{product.name}}",
      "image": "/media/{{product.image}}",
      "price": {{product.sell_price}}
      },
  {% endfor %}
```

you will have `product.price`, not `product.sell_price` in Vue. Or you have to
change line above to `"sell_price": {{product.sell_price}}`

3. Soon you will face troubles with `item` variable. As you have `item` in django context, not in Vue data. You should add items to Vue data as you did for `products`.
4. In general consider change of your approach from mixing django template and Vue code to:

- Django delivers data to Vue
- Vue generating All html and doing your js functions

OR

- use Django Rest framework(https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to provide rest API
- and use Vue only on frontend, load your data from server and put your changes to server by REST calls (using axios for example)

Good luck.

Comment: i solved this issue by adding the delimiters as you suggested now i get some little problem considering the categories filter.The products belonging to the some categories id are not showing properly .Before there was no `addtoCart(product)` function and it was working now i added this link and now it is not working.Is there any solution for this?Thank you for your help

Comment: DRF (django-rest-framework) is not necessary to implement a rest API in Django - you can use ligther (and less intrusive) packages or just do it manually (a rest API its just django views serving json instead of serving html....)

Comment: About `categories` and `products` again you have confusion in Vue data and Django context.  `product` in django loop will be taken from `category.product_set.all` but inside that loop Vue will take `product` from `filteredProducts` - not from django (not from categories).
(Note: I can not see your last changes to source files, if any - better provide github gist or so with your source).